# Put space after two consequent characters [0-9][A-F][a-f]

Tags: regex

I have a text file with hexadecimal represented numbers. These numbers are separated either by `space` or by `new line` in a 16bits chunks like this:

```
1822 0000 da12
0030 0110 0030
```

I want them in groups again, but in 8bit chunks like this:

```
18 22 00 00 da 12
00 30 01 10 00 30
```

I use "Sublime Text 3" editor, that supports regular expression find and replace. Unfortunately, my regex knowledge is pretty poor. Google search didn't help as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})` with `$1 $2`.

Comment: Yes it works. But I am kind of interested in learning regex. Therefore I was trying to understand this expression. My guess is that $1 specifies the first group surrounded by () and $2 respectively the second one. Could you please shed some light on what is going on?

Comment: That's correct @Hairi. And each group matches exactly two characters - set by the `{2}`, where each character is one of those in brackets (the possible hex characters). And so the regex in sublime moves along hungrily searching for the first match, does the replace which adds the space, and then moves through your text looking for the next match...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a positive look ahead. Replace `(\S{2})(?=\S)` with `\1`

Answer (score 0):

Different regex libraries work a little differently. I'd recommend checking out regex101.com where you can try out various regular expressions and see the results in a clear way.

Here's a possible starting point for you:

```
find: ([0-9a-f][0-9a-f])([0-9a-f][0-9a-f]) (...
replace: \1 \2 \3 \4
```

Depending on which regex library your editor uses, the replace may be $1 $2 $3 instead, or the find parenthesis or brackets may need to be escaped.